# How to add Microsoft.Kinect.dll to COM Interop C# Class

Tags: c#, matlab, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am using MATLAB to process Kinect information retrieved from C#.
During this process, I've already performed various actions, and they all perform correctly.

I can retrieve the information that is not dependent of the SDK, but i would like to use some functions of the SDK also. The problem is that I do not know how to add the Microsoft.Kinect reference to this kind of library.

I've searched but the common answer is project--> add reference, and in COM Interop there is no such possibility.

The "easy" answer would be:

{using Microsoft.Kinect}

but it doesn't allow me. SDK is fully installed and correctly working.

[image]

Comment: Have you registered the dll for COM interop? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shyb58c9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: nop, gonna give it a try.

Comment: @TylerReid it didnt work.