# C# - Passing variables to Matlab

Tags: c#, matlab

Typical google search came out empty, some I'm calling upon your great minds:
How can I pass variables from a C# class I'm writing to Matlab (with which I interface via the "NET.addAssembly" function)??

Is there a .dll file I should reference in my C# code? If yes, where is it?
Are there some documentations and examples how to pass variables from C# to Matlab?
How can I cast C# native variables into Matlab arrays?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not straightforward but you can do it.

First, you need to compile a *.DLL Library using C#.
You need to create a c# COM interop class using public and private functions. - [How to add Microsoft.Kinect.dll to COM Interop C# Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684696/how-to-add-microsoft-kinect-dll-to-com-interop-c-sharp-class)

Then, you need to:

-Run CMD as Administrator

-Open C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0 (or similar) folder

-cd path directory in the CMD window

-copy NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS.cs to that folder

-copy and paste csc /t:library NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS.cs

-copy and paste regasm NAME_OF_YOUR_CLASS.dll /tlb /codebase

-Open Matlab and use net.Framework to access the available functions

In MATLAB, you need to:

net = actxserver('ImageCreationMatlab.ImageCreationMatlabClass');
val = net.depthKinectTwo(filename,'kdpt',0,0,1);

This is just an example following the other question DLL.

I'll try to find the links/tutorial for the class creation.