# Matlab .NET assembly with C#

Tags: c#, matlab

Im having a very strange issue with integrating a matlab .NET Assembly with C#.
When I try using the DLL in a console application project everything works just fine.
When I change the project to a class library (without changing anything but adding a constructor to the class) I get an exception when attempting to load an Instance of the Matlab Object.
The exception I get is:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: Trouble initializing libraries required by .NET Assembly.

   at MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Utility.MWMCR..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MtlObj..cctor()}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you check what the differences are in the .csproj file after you changed it? (on file level)

And also you can try to remove the reference and add it, maybe the Console application adds something to the Reference tag that a class library is not expecting.

Comment: The only thing that changes is <OutputType>Exe</OutputType> to <OutputType>Library</OutputType>. Also I tried playing around with the references.. no luck there :(

Comment: Can you share the code how you call the library at first?

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your DLL?
Are you calling the methods correctly?

Please check this thread - [C# - Passing variables to Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685863/c-sharp-passing-variables-to-matlab/36690220#36690220)

Are you sure your making all these steps?